# Identify the active Office application in OfficeJS Office add-in

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-addins, office-js

I am developing an OfficeJS office add-in for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint.

How can I used JS to determine which Office App is active (i.e. Word, Excel, PP) so I can condition on the active application?

For example, if Word is active call X, else if Excel is active call Y, if PowerPoint call Z.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the new set of APIs?
If so you could check using the requirements set model for them.
https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements
e.g.:

```
if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1))
{
    // Do something in word
} else if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', 1.1))
{
    // Do something in excel
}
```